# How do I change a movie-clip's frame when it isn't on the current frame? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, timeline

I want to be able to change a movie clip frame that is off the screen currently, but will be back on the screen later. I want the frame to change from 1 to 2 on the movie-clip only if the overall timeline reaches a certain point.
So if the timeline reaches frame 5 or a specified frame, the movie-clip will change from 1 to 2. So, when I go back to the frame with the movie-clip on it, it stays on movie-clip 2.

**To explain what I am trying to do:**
I named the frame "index" that has the movie-clip and I want parts that the viewer navigated to already to be a movie-clip that changes color or animation. When they go back to the index, the movie-clip will stay on the second frame of the animation.

I am sort of new to action script and I've spent hours trying to figure out how to do this, so any help would greatly be appreciated.

---

I don't really know how to target something that isn't in the current frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this into the MovieClip:

```
function checkParent(e:Event):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    if(parent && (parent as MovieClip).currentFrame > 5)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkParent);
```

Comment: That works nicely for detecting and changing the frame if the movie-clip itself was past frame 5, but unfortunately when I go back to index it doesn't keep the movie-clip on the second frame. When I place the movie-clip further in, it does work though.